# Twitter Authentication In Fancybox Or lightbox

Tags: php, authentication, twitter, fancybox, fancybox-2

This is a question i think is worthwhile to know and useful for others, because i think a lot of people love those fancybox and lightbox pop ups rather than the normal window pop ups you usually get.

I am asking a question if this is possible to put the twitter authentication inside a fancybox/lightbox, so once a user clicks the **Sign In With Twitter** button, it then opens that inside a nice fancybox or even a lightbox?

I did some searches via google and stackoverflow, i can't find anything relevant that helps answer this question?

So currently i now have this page https://www.tubenations.com/twitter.php (note this link won't work unless you have an account and are logged in!)

I already have fancybox installed on my site for other elements, but i just think it would look nicer if this was possible to put the twitter auth screen inside fancybox?

so the current setup is as follows on my twitter.php page

```
<hr>
<div class="twitterInfo2">In order for you to view and appear on this page you need to authenticate your twitter account by clicking sign in with twitter button below!
  <br />
</div>
<br />
<a href="/twitter/process.php">
  <img class="twitterImage" src="/twitter/images/sign-in-with-twitter.png" title="Tube Nations Link Your Twitter" alt="Tube Nations Link Your Twitter" />
</a>
<hr>
```

so basically it is the **/twitter/process.php** file that does the work, I will post the code for the process.php file too, because I also think that file needs to be adjusted with the fancybox inclusion code if it is at all possible??

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['token']  !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {

//If token is old, distroy session and redirect user to index.php
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');

}elseif(isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {

//Successful response returns oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, user_id, and screen_name
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['token'] , $_SESSION['token_secret']);
$access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

include_once("../inc/header_session.php");

    if($connection->http_code == '200' && $tn_userid != 1)
{
    //Redirect user to twitter
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'verified';
    $_SESSION['request_vars'] = $access_token;

//Insert user into the database
    $user_info = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials'); 
    $name = explode(" ",$user_info->name);
    $fname = isset($name[0])?$name[0]:'';
    $lname = isset($name[1])?$name[1]:'';
    $db_user = new Users();
    $db_user->checkUsers('twitter',$user_info->id,$user_info->screen_name,$fname,$lname,$user_info->lang,$access_token['oauth_token'],$access_token['oauth_token_secret'],$user_info->profile_image_url,$user->data['user_id']);

        //Unset no longer needed request tokens
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    unset($_SESSION['token_secret']);
    header('Location: /twitter.php');
}else{
    die("error, try again later!");
}         }


}else{

if(isset($_GET["denied"]))
{
    header('Location: /twitter.php');
    die();
}

    //Fresh authentication
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

//Received token info from twitter
$_SESSION['token']          = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['token_secret']   = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];


    //Any value other than 200 is failure, so continue only if http code is 200
if($connection->http_code == '200')
{
    //redirect user to twitter
    $twitter_url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token']);
    header('Location: ' . $twitter_url); 
}else{
    die("error connecting to twitter! try again later!");
}}
```

I hope it is possible?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement, and "Is this possible" is not a question.  Are you getting a specific error?  What behavior did you expect, and what behavior are you actually getting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, well it was a question to ask if this was possible? not that i have tried yet, it was a question that i think is worthwhile to ask and could be useful for others to know too? the reason i posted some code of my site was just incase it is possible and if someone knows a way to get it to work?

Comment: "Is this possible" is not a question; it's a proxy for "How do I do this?"  Anything is possible given enough time, money and programmer effort.  Did you read my answer on your meta question?

Comment: yes i did, and all it says is pretty much what your saying in the comment i replied to here, I have always liked fancybox and that is why i would love it if i could put a lot of things inside them. But i have read conflicting info, so say its possible some say it is not, i have tried in the past to put other elements inside them, but failed, but i never used stackoverflow then.